# Geolocation service does not get my real location

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation

Services like geojson, etc...
Obtains the location of my ISP through my public IP, not my real location.
e.g. the ISP is in Buenos Aires and I am in Neuquen.

How to get the real location?

Comment: Geolocation is not an exact science, it depends on the ISP to provide detailed information to the services. Some ISPs don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most common sources of location information are IP address, Wi-Fi and Bluetooth MAC address, radio-frequency identification (RFID), Wi-Fi connection location, or device Global Positioning System (GPS) and GSM/CDMA cell IDs.

The IP address geolocation is not always accurate because the range can be reallocated easily.

The most accurate way is using GPS.

Source: http://www.geolocation.com